# Securing Post between two Application different servers

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, http-post, access-token

Guys I have two application where this scenario.

Application A (VB.NET) sends a request to Application B (C#) via HttpPts like this:

```
Dim strform As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
...here I build a form with post method where I pass an Token that I receive from an STS
```

So when I send the post I capture the Token on the Application B when I receive the request, and I send it back to the STS where is validated, and this throw me false or true as a result of the validation.

And I was thinking that if a hacker for example capture the token before the application A send it to the applicaation B and build the form like the application A does could enter the application without any problem

I would like two know if there any way to secure that token to be unique of that httppost request.

Thank you guys, Best Regards.

EDIT:

This is the form that I use to get the other page from the destination server.

This code is generated by the strinbuilder from above.

```
<form id='PostForm' name='PostForm' action='http://myserverdestination.com/ichub/page.aspx' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='token' value='rawToken6lakhdslkjasdjasdasjdjasd'></form>
```

And when I get to the destination I have a Page_Load Method where I receive de Request and extract the Token value from the post.

```
var token = Request.Form["token"]
```

Now imagine there´s a maliciuos guy plugged to the network, I don´t know, and one of the users authorized are using this form to request a page from the destination server, those users request first a Token fron my STS but the maliciuous guy capture this form somehow, he will try to get in wiht the Token successfully, right?

My question is How to make every user request unique to set the Token just for that user?

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify a bit more to get a solid answer; your question is quite unclear. Could you post some of your code? In addition, it is worth noting that, if you are using HTTPS, it would be much harder for an eavesdropper to steal the token, and you can use techniques like certificate pinning to mitigate man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks  @F.StephenQ